# How to check GN 125H battery

Tags: battery, motorcycle, suzuki

GN-125H haven't battery indicator and not a kick starter.

How to know battery status.
How to know battery was in deadline.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: No sir some quick tool do you know

Answer (score 0):

Without a multimeter to measure battery voltage, either borrow a battery or try boosting the battery from a car (12v) for starting. Another method that may work if the battery has some charge left would be a running start where the motorcycle is pushed to start with high gear. As noted by Dan K, I neglected to mention having ignition ON.  Someone pushing while you have the high gear selected but clutch handle pulled to disengage the clutch. As low speed is reached, let out the clutch (release the clutch handle) to engage the engine. If the engine starts up, pull the clutch handle to disengage to let the engine run, warmup and recharge the battery. Just enough speed is needed to rotate the engine. The electronics may have enough voltage from the battery to startup. Speed above 10-15mph/15-24kph) sould be sufficient to startup with some voltage from a dead battery.

Comment: It should be noted you need the ignition in the on position for it to work, even with a dead battery.